MODBUS failing to read
The following code fails:
var factory = new ModbusFactory();
_master = factory.CreateMaster(new TcpClient(_ip, _port));
_master.ReadHoldingRegisters(1, 49, 7);

The exception we get is this:

XXX initialization failed with the following exception: system.indexoutofrangeexception: index was outside the bounds of the array.


Stack trace:
at nmodbus.io.modbustransport.createresponse[T] (Byte[] frame)
at nmodbus.io.modbusiptransport.createmessageandinitialuzetransactionid[T] (Byte[] fullFrame)
at nmodbus.io.modbustransport.unicastmessage[T] (IModbusMessage message)
at nmodbus.device.modbusmaster.perfomreadregisters(readholdinginputregistersrequest request)
at nmodbus.device.modbusmaster.readholdingregisters(byte slaveaddress, uint16 startaddress, uint16 numberofpointa)
at chillermonitor.unisemchillermonitor.init(cancellationtoken token) in d:\projects\service.chiller\chillermonitor\unisemchillermonitor.cs:line 91

What should I be looking for / configuring?

It might be as simple as the register you are requesting does not exist on the device. I don't think it is possible to tell without more details.  RMMS might be of useful for debugging.

What are the 3 arguments / parameters for? Reading holding registers only requires 2: starting register, and number of registers. (That's a "wrapper" method you're using)
